# How i can make my drawed points clickable?

Tags: java, android

Recently i figure out how to draw point an a view using a canvas but i quickly counter an issue :

How i can make mt drawed points clickable so i can make apear a menu when the user click on them.

Actually this is how i draw my points :

```
new OnDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayerDrawn(Canvas canvas, float pageWidth, float pageHeight, int displayedPage) {
                canvas.drawPoint(pageHeight /2, pageHeight /2, paint);
                view.draw(canvas) ;
            }
        }
```

Does someone has an idea how an i can make my points clickabke or if i can use other clickable points which allows me to place them in my view with some `x` and `y` coordinates.

Thank you.

**UPDATE :**

Does someone know another way to fix my issue because the actual solution do not work.

```
      public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    int clickX = (int)(e.getX());
                    int clickY = (int)(e.getY());

                    for(int i = 0; i < issueList.size(); i++) {
                        Issue issue = issueList.get(i);
                         xPos = view.getWidth() / issue.getxScale();
                         yPos = view.getHeight() / issue.getyScale();
                         double xDistance = Math.pow(clickX - xPos, 2);
                         double yDistance = Math.pow(clickY - yPos, 2);

                        Log.d("xDistance", Double.toString(xDistance));
                        Log.d("yDistance", Double.toString(yDistance));

                        double distance = Math.sqrt(xDistance + yDistance) / view.getZoom();

                        Log.d("Distance", Double.toString(distance));
                        if(distance < 50) {
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                                vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(100, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
                            }
                            Log.d("Taped", "true");
                            return;
                        }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do 3 things:

**First**, when you draw a point always store x and y of it's center to an array.

**Second**, setOnTouchListener on the view that is drawing those points, and get x and y from the touch event like this:

```
int clickX = (int)event.getX();
int clickY = (int)event.getY();
```

And **finally** loop through the array and calculate the distance between the center of your point and the touch event for every point. If that distance is smaller then the radius of your point you have clicked the point.

```
distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(clickX - centerX, 2) + Math.pow(clickY - centerY, 2));
```

Comment: The problem i'm countering is that when i get some x and y offset due to scroll and zoom i'm not able tu use your formula for calcul the distance between the center of my point and the toutch event, do you have any ideas how i can fix that ? thank you